# Set src and dst img the same for opencv resize function

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to resize an `cv::Mat img` with OpenCV. When I am using function `cv::resize()`, I set `src` and `dst` img to be the same as input img like `cv::resize(img, img)`. And when I test the program, so far it works correctly. But I am a bit confused how the resize function is implemented cause when I read the documentation it said we need to pre-allocate the `dst` img before resizing.

Can anyone explain it to me?
Thanks.

Comment: You dont need to preallocate dst in the c++ version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Micka, you don't need to pre-allocate `dst`. But you can, if you want to, with different calling conventions.

From [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize):

- The function `resize` resizes the image `src` down to or up to the specified size. Note that the initial `dst` type or size are not taken into account. Instead, the size and type are derived from the `src`, `dsize`, `fx` , and `fy` . If you want to resize `src` so that it fits the pre-created `dst`, you may call the function as follows:

  ```
  // explicitly specify dsize=dst.size(); fx and fy will be computed from that.
  resize(src, dst, dst.size(), 0, 0, interpolation);
  ```

Comment: I guess the resize() will use some sort of buffer to store the resized img before it copies to dst img, right? Cause we can use resize(img, img).